# EXCEL: Array in a cell. How to get the array back?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have in B2 the formula `=ROW(A1:A3)`. This formula gives an array of `{1;2;3}`. Because a cell only holds one value, cell `B2` displays a value of `1`. Any place in the worksheet, the formula `=B2` gives `1`, not the array. Yet, Excel still remembers the array because the formula is still in `B2`.

Is there any way to get the array back so it, the whole array, not its individual elements, can be used for further manipulation? I'm looking for something like `OPERATION(B2) = {1;2;3}`. For example, `SUMPRODUCT(OPERATION(B2)) = SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:A3)) = 6`.

[image]

Comment: Does B2 have `=ROW(A1:A3)` or `{=ROW(A1:A3)}`? It might make a difference. In any event, I don't think that on the level of standard worksheet functions you can do this, but in VBA you have `Range("B2").Formula` which could be parsed.

Comment: Interesting question. You can potentially store your formula in Name Manager (e.g. Rows = `=ROW(Sheet1!A1:A3)`) and then use it as a reference in Excel formulas, like `=INDEX(Rows,2,1)`.

Comment: @John Coleman B2 contains "=ROW(A1:A3)", not the CSE version.

Comment: @JustynaMK I suggest you post that as an answer.  I use that method frequently.

Comment: @Justyna I think defining a name is the closest thing I can get.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld I just did that. + Joehua glad the workaround works for you.

Comment: Another thing one could try (never done so myself) would be to use Indirect with Formula function. However using named ranges might just be preferred

Comment: Find a good lawyer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround, you can store your formula in Name Manager, e.g.:

[image]

Then you can use it as a reference in Excel formulas, like `=INDEX(Rows,2,1)`:

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner's answer down below is exactly what I was looking for, a function that can use cell address directly to get the array. Unfortunately, that feature doesn't exist in Excel 2010. For my version of Excel, your answer is as close as it can get.

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is not the answer to the OP's question as they do not have the latest Office 365.  I put this here for those who come later and do have it.

---

With the latest Office 365 with Dynamic array formulas this problem is now gone.

Putting `=ROW(1:3)` or the equivalent dynamic array formula `=SEQUENCE(3)` Excel will spill the array down automatically without the need of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

And now one can refer to the array by only refering to `A1` by putting `#` after the reference:

```
=SUM(A1#)
```

[image]

Then no matter how the array in `A1` changes the other formula does not need to be changed.

The caveat is that the formula in A1 needs the room to spill down.  If there is a cell that has anything in it that resides in the spill down array it will return an error.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Seems I need to upgrade my Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Just to try and clarify this, arrays in Excel before the September 2018 update for Office 365 don't self-expand like they do in Google sheets, so if you put an array into a single cell you just get the first element of the array (see column A for example).

If you want to enter the array directly into the sheet, you have to select the cells you want it to occupy (say B2:B4) and enter it as an array formula (see column B) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can still use the array in another formula as long as it's expecting an array - e.g. with sumproduct you get the correct total, 6 (see column C).

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:A3))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't always work without entering the whole formula as an array formula (see column D).

```
=SUM(ROW(A1:A3))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

@JvDV is correct, you don't always get the first element of an array expression entered into a single cell - see [this reference](https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection) for explanation of the implicit intersection mechanism.

Comment: You wouldn't always just get the first element of an array though Tom, it's depending on the implicit intersection mechanism.

Comment: Ah yes, I was oversimplifying there - would you like to add more?

Comment: Hi, Tom, I have added a screen dump and also elaborated on my question to clarify it. What I would like to get back is the array as seen by pressing F9.

Answer (score 0):

I have two methods, which might qualify as solutions or workarounds, depending on what technology you're willing to accept.

Both rely on retrieving the formula that produces the array from `B2` and then evaluating that formula each time you invoke your `OPERATION(B2)`.

## Method 1: VBA

Create a UDF:

```
Function Arr(R as Range)
    Arr = Application.Evaluate(R.Formula)
End Function
```

which you then invoke in a cell, e.g. `=SUM(Arr(B2))`.

## Method 2: Name Manager + EVALUATE()

Note that this is different from Justyna's answer. The idea is to allow you to specify the address of the cell holding the array-generating formula.

Create a name that holds `=EVALUATE(FORMULATEXT(INDIRECT(INDEX($1:$1048576;ROW();COLUMN()+1))))`. This way you can specify that you want the content of the cell `B2` by writing the string `B2` to the nearest cell to the right of the cell in which you're using your newly created name.

Unfortunately, `EVALUATE()` cannot be used within a cell.