# How get an array result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to follow this [example](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-match) to get the last value in a range but Im failing on the very first step.

The formula should be:

```
ROW(names)-MIN(ROW(names))+1
```

And return an array:

```
{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}
```

When I do the same I only get a number

[image]

The only difference is my Excel is in Spanish so `ROW()` is `FILA()` and I use the range instead of a named range.

```
=FILA(B1:B6) - MIN(FILA(B1:B6)) + 1
```

Comment: A cell cannot hold more than one value and as such it is only showing the first.  That formula is meant to be used in junction with other formula as it returns an array.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544078/excel-array-in-a-cell-how-to-get-the-array-back/59546045#59546045

Comment: I see, I was trying to do things step by step to make sure has the right values.

Comment: The current formula does not return the array `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}`. But when you use `INDEX`, you can see what does get returned: `=INDEX(ROW(names)-MIN(ROW(names))+1;)` > `{1;2;3;4;5;6}`